# How to format a column with awk and printf when values are either numeric or string

Tags: string, awk, formatting, printf, numeric

I have the following file, where I want to left-pad with zeros when the value is numeric, but leave it as it is when value is a string:

```
cat test.txt 
2032
12
XXXXX
507
334
```

This works only for numeric values, the string being ignored:

```
awk '{printf "%05d\n",$1}' test.txt 
02032
00012
00000
00507
00334
```

I can get it with a condition, but is there a simpler way ?

```
awk '{if ($1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/) printf "%05d\n",$1; else printf "%s\n",$1}' test.txt 
02032
00012
XXXXX
00507
00334
```

Comment: What does "numeric" mean in your context? For example, which if any of "2.3", ".5", "NaN", "Inf", "1e3" are numeric?

Comment: Here, numeric would be integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your awk solution is ok. if your "**simpler**" means "**shorter**":

```
awk '$0*1==$0{$0=sprintf("%05d",$0)}1' file
```

or

```
awk '/^[0-9]+$/{$0=sprintf("%05d",$0)}1' file
```

or

```
awk '$0*1==$0{printf("%05d\n",$0);next}1' file
```

or if you are sure there is no empty line in your file:

```
awk '$0=$0*1==$0?sprintf("%05d",$0):$0' file
```

in examples above, I used $0, not $1, since in your input example, there is only one column.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solutions. In my 'real' file, there are several columns with that potential double format, that's why I wanted a better solution than my if condition above.

Comment: What does the 1 mean at the end of your first 3 solutions ?

Comment: @SébastienClément `1` is a boolean expression, means `true`. awk will print $0 if true. you can try `seq 10|awk '$0%2'` then you will understand.